# Why is my VBA PasteSpecial, Operation:= xlAdd doubling the cell values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a very simple macro that takes the value from the same cell in each timesheet and adds the values using Paste special into a summary table.

No errors are appearing but the end value is double what it should be. Have I misunderstood how xladd works or is my code somehow running twice?

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ws.Range("D13:E14").Copy     
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("D13:D14").PasteSpecial 
        Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
  End If
Next
```

As an example I expect the output from 6 sheets where cell D13=1 to be 6 hours. What I am actually getting is 12 hours.

Comment: with the above code you loop all worksheets and you paste data in worksheet "summary" in the same location, that why it is over write.  Your aim is to copy .range("D13:E14") from all sheets and paste all data in worksheet SUMMARY one under the other?

Comment: The aim is to add each worksheet to give a total in one cell.

Comment: I just tested your code and the output was what is expected. Do you have hidden sheets?

Comment: It sounds like you only want to copy the value from D13, not D13:D14? Is that correct? Please clarify?

Comment: You are also adding... so if you run it twice it will, yes, double the value.

Comment: I want to copy each value from a range of cells into the same cell in the summary sheet. so all values of D13 -> summary D13, all values of D14 -> summary D14

Comment: You are also, as mentioned, adding to whatever values are currently in the summary sheet.

Comment: @AndyG good point on noting that it will add to values that were already there

Comment: I pasted your code into a standard module dummy Sub.  It looks like you're missing ` _` after `PasteSpecial` But even after correcting that I get a run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Why have you chosen to spell ***summary*** two different ways ??

Comment: @Andy G There's an earlier bit of code that clears SUMMARY before running the code in order to avoid that issue.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Yeah, my bad, pretty much the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided works fine when i create an empty workbook, name one sheet summary, and add a few other sheets. **I believe your code is going through other worksheets that contain values which are not supposed to get added in.**

Check your workbook for:

- hidden sheets
- very hidden sheets (in VBE)

My test code looks like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("D13:D14").Clear

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ws.Range("D13:E14").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("D13:D14").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. 
There are no hidden sheets or very hidden sheets that I can see in VBE. 
To clarify when you run the code with values of 1 In D13 & D14 for three sheets your summary sheet would give you a total of 3 in D13 & D14?

Comment: Ah no. I lie. Just found some. Thank you!

Comment: This still produces 6 if you have 3 sheets with 1s in the copied cells and SUMMARY is the last sheet in the workbook.  It works OK if SUMMARY is the first sheet.

Comment: Actually it was a labelling error. My sheet was titled "SUMMARY", The code referenced  
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then. 
Changed this, removed hidden sheets. All solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to test if something goes wrong. in case of non numeric values you will get an error because the variables store sums are declare as doubles.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim D13 As Double, D14 As Double, E13 As Double, E14 As Double

    With ThisWorkbook

        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            With ws
                If .Name <> "Summary" Then
                    D13 = D13 + .Range("D13").Value
                    D14 = D14 + .Range("D14").Value
                    E13 = E13 + .Range("E13").Value
                    E14 = E14 + .Range("E14").Value
                End If
            End With
        Next ws

        With .Worksheets("SUMMARY")
            .Range("D13").Value = D13
            .Range("D14").Value = D14
            .Range("E13").Value = E13
            .Range("E14").Value = E14
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces correct results if SUMMARY is the first tab in your workbook.  If SUMMARY is after the first tab then anything in SUMMARY will be added to itself because `If ws.Name <> "Summary"` returns TRUE - the `String`s `"SUMMARY"` and `"Summary"` are not the same so your `IF` statement runs on `Worksheets("SUMMARY")` as it loops through the sheets.

Also, if you run your code without including a command to clear the `Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("D13:E14")` before adding any values to it, it will add values on each iteration.

References in code to `Sheets("Summary") do work because Sheet and Range names in VBA are not case sensitive.

```
Sub AddToSUMMARY()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("D13:E14").Clear
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "SUMMARY" Then
            ws.Range("D13:E14").Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("D13:D14").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```